# Apply functions to nested list inside pandas rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following df and I'm trying to figure out how to extract the unique values from each list in each row in order to simplify my df.

[image]

As if you were to apply `unique()` to the first row and then you get 'NEUTRALREGION' only once. Please note that I have another 4 columns with the same requirements.

Comment: If the values in the lists are always same, you can simply do `df["Neutral_Partners"].str[0]`.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of your dataframe that we can reconstruct not an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using `df.applymap(lambda x: set(x))`.

That allowed me to check the unique values in each cell.